# Calling String.prototype.substring with Infinity as second parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a function very similar to:

```js
const processString = (input, maxSize = Infinity) => {
  return input
    // More 'input' chained transformations (e.g. .padStart())
    .substring(0, maxSize)
    // More 'input' chained transformations (e.g. .padStart())
}

const assertString = "Lorem ipsum"

console.assert(processString(assertString, 5) === "Lorem")
console.assert(processString(assertString) === assertString)
```

while this works fine, I was wondering, whether it isn't a bad practise to call the `String.prototype.substring` with `Infinity` as a second parameter since I couldn't find it mentioned anywhere in the docs.

The reason I'm doing this, is that I have multiple chained calls before and after the `.substring` call and I would like to keep the implementation this way, rather than breaking it into separate variables and conditions.

I basically have two questions:

1. Is it ok to call String.prototype.substring with Infinity as second parameter?
2. Alternatively, what would be a different way of accomplishing the same result?

Comment: I wouldn't set a default value to maxSize since [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)'s second parameter is optional. Optional is equivalent of `undefined`.

Comment: I honestly feel so dumb rn ... that makes total sense. Thx

Comment: Is there any way I can tag comment as an accepted answer?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think that comments can be accepted as answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how this could be a bad practise if you really need a second param.
The only way I see that could be more robust is using `input.length`

```js
const processString = (input, maxSize = input.length) => {
  return input
    // More 'input' chained transformations (e.g. .padStart())
    .substring(0, maxSize)
    // More 'input' chained transformations (e.g. .padStart())
}

const assertString = "Lorem ipsum"

console.assert(processString(assertString, 5) === "Lorem")
console.assert(processString(assertString) === assertString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Max length is `Math.pow(2, 53) - 1`.

Have a look at this:
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type.

> The String type is the set of all ordered sequences of zero or more 16-bit unsigned integer values (“elements”) up to a maximum length of 2^53-1 elements.

You can set it as a constant and use

```js
const MAX_STRING_LENGTH = Math.pow(2, 53) - 1; // 9007199254740991
```

Comment: It's up to you. It's hard to imagine case when you have a string like this anyway :)
I just posted real max value to make your default value more accurate